# How do I get the reference of an activity I opened using intent?

Tags: java, android

Inside my MainActivity I open my SecondActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

How do I get the reference of this instance of SecondActivity inside my MainActivity?

```
//inside MainActivity
SecondActivity object = // make it equal to instance created above
```

Comment: use this key word for get instance of activity inside that.

Comment: will that work if I am trying to get the reference in MainActivity?

Comment: edit your question, you want to get instance of activity outside of that activity , means in other activity or what is your need?

Comment: Soz, I want the reference inside my MainActvity

Comment: "How do I get the reference of this instance of SecondActivity inside my MainActivity?" -- you don't. Activities are loosely-coupled components.

Comment: You write your code such that you don't have to.  If you think you need this, your architecture is wrong.

Comment: thanks for the advice!

Answer (score -2):

Pass your a handler to the second one via trigger intent, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Handler", handler);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your SecondActivity post message and data, maybe the instance of SecondActivity.this or another you like, to the handler.